# IOS Swift Date Comparison

Tags: swift

I have been hunting around but am having a hard time locating **current relevant information that deals with a simple date year comparison**. Most of the answers around googlesphere are a bit more console side rather than application side...

I have gotten a bit of the code wrote with the help of some tutorials ( this is my first ios app)

My issue is the integarValue does not work with NSDate and causes me an error. Having a hard time getting NSDateTimeInterval to work in my favor also...All help is greatly appreciated!!

```
    //grab the date needed
    var chosenDate = self.datePick.date

    //create todays date variable for math
    var todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()

    // create a formatter
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"

    //time interval since now


    //grab the diff in years and display amount of years difference
    let day = formatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate.integarValue) - formatter.stringFromDate(chosenDate.integarValue)
    let result = "\(day)"

    //create alert controller
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: result, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


    //add button to alert
    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    //show alert
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let yearsDifference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: datePick.date, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil).year
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your option and it built without issues however breaks when it calls the code for the button to do the math.

    let yearsDif =   NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: datePick.date, toDate: NSDate(), options:nil).year
        
        //create alert controller
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Based on results:", message: String(yearsDif), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

Comment: try yearsDifference.description or "\\(yearsDifference)"

Comment: I goofed and had a break point on my app causing the issue. All is well thank you!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. **Spelling**

   integ**e**r, not integ**a**r,
2. **Use NSDate in `-stringFromDate`**

   `-stringFromDate` accepts an `NSDate` as its argument, so your code should look like this:
   `formatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)`
3. **Convert string back to integer before subtracting**

   `stringFromDate` returns a `String`, and there is no default definition for binary subtraction between `String` objects, so you must use `toInt()` and then unwrap the value with `!` before you subtract

   ```
   todaysDateString = formatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
   println(todaysDateString-1) // This will give you an error
   todaysDateInteger = todaysDateString.toInt()!
   println(todaysDateInteger-1) // This works
   ```

**Putting it all together**

```
//grab the diff in years and display amount of years difference
let day = formatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate).toInt()! - formatter.stringFromDate(chosenDate).toInt()!
```

This is what that line of code should look like.

Comment: Does not seem integerValue is a method that will work for me. :\ I continue to receive "string" does not have a valid member named integerValue

Comment: Thanks!! I will give this a shot pretty soon. Been trying to mess with the above poster's solution as well hehe.